# mCustomSrollbar inside immediate function, why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mcustomscrollbar

This is my code:

**jQuery**

```
(function($) {
    $(window).load(function(){
        $(".bottomWrapperTable").mCustomScrollbar({
            axis: "y",
            theme: "dark",
            scrollbarPosition: "outside",
            callbacks: {
                whileScrolling: function(){
                    setScroll(this.mcs.left);
                },
                onScroll: function() {
                    setStartEndScroll(this.mcs.leftPct);
                }
            }
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

I followed the mCustomScrollar [documentation](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/) to produce this code.

My question is, why does this function have to be within the immediate funtion even though `window.load()` is not called until **after** the DOM is ready anyway?

I have tried removing the immediate function but appears to not call the function at all.
I also tried putting the code within `$(function() {}` but still no luck.

**NOTE:** I am not encountering a problem, just requesting information on this topic.

Any insight into this would be helpful

Comment: Its a practice called 'iffy'. It means you do not create any implicit globals. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression

Comment: you can remove it and replace all `$` signs with `jQuery`

Comment: @GudzDaniel can you explain a bit more? Are you saying I can remove the immediate function and replace, for example, `$(window).load()` with `jQuery(window).load()`?

Comment: yes, iife is used for 
1) local scope(not to create global variables), 
2) rename variables like as you can see in your code iife invokes with the `jQuery` param and the function get that `jQuery` but renames it to `$` locally

Comment: Thank you to both of you! Helped clear up some confusion